# Session variables in ServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to access session variables through a filter. I don't even know if it is possible. In practice, the problem is that the `doFilter` method type from `javax.Servlet.Filter` implementation is `ServletRequest`, whilst HttpServlet inherited classes, doPost method parameter `request` is HttpServletRequest.

1. Can I access session in ServletRequest in a Filter?
2. Should I do that?
3. What could you recommend me?

Thanks!

Comment: `HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) methodRequest;` You can cast the doFilter request to a `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just cast the obtained [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) to [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlet-filters wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: u r right. I am so regular to cast `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` that fogot to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. `ServletRequest` allows you access to session that contains attributes. You can review, add, remove and modify attributes whenever you want either in filter, servlet, jsp, session listener. This technique is very useful and especially attended for communication between different components within the same session.

Comment: [The `ServletRequest` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) doesn't have a `getSession()` method. The OP would otherwise not have asked this question in first place.