# Running a specific method bedore process request

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, request

I've written the following class:

```
public class GreetChecker implements java.io.Serializable {

    public GreetChecker() {
    }

    public static boolean greetSessionChecker(HttpSession session, String attribute) {
        Enumeration<String> attr = session.getAttributeNames();
        while(attr.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String elem = attr.nextElement();
            if (elem.equals(attribute))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and I would that every servlet invoke that method before process incoming request. I have to invoke that method explicitly in any servlet or there is a suitable config for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ServletRequestListener`:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class ServletRequestListenerDemo  implements ServletRequestListener
{

          public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent arg0)
          {
            System.out.print("The Request object destroyed at  :"+new java.util.Date());
          }
          public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent req)
          {


             HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
             HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
             yourmethod(session);
          }
}
```

For a more flexible solution you might want to look into Servlet Filters using the @WebFilter annotation.

To get to the session, see: [Session variables in ServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009784/session-variables-in-servletrequest)

Comment: How can I get HTTPSession in that method?

Comment: @St.Antario the ServletRequestEvent has a getServletRequest method that returns a ServletRequest. When you cast that to a HttpServletRequest, you can call getSession on that.

Comment: @St.Antario I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Ok, how to get current request inside _requestInitiaized()_?

Comment: @St.Antario I even added the two lines of code from the link to the answer.. :)