# Access a JSF (2.3) managed bean in filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, managed-bean

I have a Bean annotated as `@SessionScoped`:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bUser")
@SessionScoped
public class BUser implements Serializable {
    private Integer userId = 0;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

And I have a filter class (`javax.servlet.Filter`), which will be used as a router:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Get bUser bean property

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

How can I access the `bUser` bean and its properties?

Comment: See [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112)

Comment: I read it before. But in my case: `BUser bUser = (BUser) request.getAttribute("bUser");` returns null. `request.getSession()` does not exists.

Comment: Of course session attributes are not available on the request. In order to get the session, [just cast request to `HttpServletRequest`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009784/session-variables-in-servletrequest).

Comment: By the way, since you're as per your edit apparently using JSF 2.3 while this is not final yet, I'd like to warn that **JSF 2.3 will deprecate `@ManagedBean`**. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4347707 Additional advantage with CDI is that you don't need to manually mess with loose attribtues this way.

Comment: @Df.fpm This will be the case on the user's very first call to your app. The session object is about to be created, your `BUser` bean will be created on its first use within a JSF page.

Comment: BalusC, f_puras, you are right. Should i remove post?

Comment: Not necessary. Duplicates feed search engines with new keywords. Moreover, deletions may account to question bans.

Comment: @Df.fpm Just leave it here. The original question did not explicitely mention Filters, so you're adding a new aspect.

Comment: Who voted for reopen? Please undo that vote. That makes no sense.